# What is the best way to create seed dynamically for Dynamic placeholder in Sitecore 9

Tags: best-practices, dynamic-placeholder

I am creating a Materialize-UI based Grid (CMS authorable) to reduce no of fixed/static layouts in the application. 
CMS side - I've created Row & Column templates, One grid rendering & Datasource (which has row & it's child columns with required materialize info). 
Code side - I've used hard code seed value i.e. 10 for the dynamic placeholder inside a foreach loop which runs equals to the no of columns suppose 5 in the datasource. For each iteration, the seed value increments by 1 (seed = 11, 12, 13, 14, 15) and creates 5 dynamic placeholders which are used to add 5 renderings/components on the page. It works fine when i publish and run the page.

However, when i delete the 4th column from the datasource, publish and run the page then, the component which was set for seed no 15, doesn't load, Because this time seed no 15 is not created which is set in the presentation details of the page.

To resolve this issue, I thought of adding a seed id for each row & column in the CMS & use that for dynamic placeholder creation and it works fine for me.

However, I think this is hard for content author to assign unique id for each Row & Column in the CMS. Therefore, I am looking for a good solution here to handle seed value dynamically?

Comment: That sounds like a potential bug with Sitecore 9.x

Comment: This doesn't fully make sense, you are generating Placeholder in code (not in the ideal way, but that's a separate issue), but removing a rendering from inside the Placeholder is causing it to not be created? Can you post the code you use to create your palceholders.

Comment: Any suggestion guys?

Comment: [code]@{ int index = int(default); int seedVal = 10; }  <div class="container"> @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("grid-row", seed: 10) </div> Below columns will be placed in grid-row placeholder <div class="row"> @foreach (var gridColumn in Model.GridColumns) { seedVal = seedVal + index; @Html.Sitecore().DynamicPlaceholder("grid-column", CreateColumnWrapper(gridColumn), seed: seedVal) } </div> Note: CreateColumnWrapper(gridColumn)

Comment: This is a very strange use of Dynamic Placeholders, and wrong IMO. Rather than creating each `gridColumn` as placeholder, you should just write the html straight out. You wouldn't have this issue then.

Comment: Thanks Jammy. Basically, I am coding a materialize based & CMS authorable Grid. The idea behind this is to reduce the no of fixed layouts in the application. Content author just need to create different grid datasources (Combination of rows and columns) as per their requirement & add on any page using the grid rendering. Now the coding logic reads the rows & no of columns information and wrap with the html. using this content author can run the page in the EE mode and add no of components in the columns. Hope you understood?

Comment: I wouldn't create Placeholders for this, I would simply write out the HTML for the rows/columns based on the DS. I would only create Placeholders to allow the user to add components from the Experience Editor (i.e. not programatically based on DS). Creating a row/column grid is not hard since you can [put logic in the tag builder](https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/sitecore-9-dynamic-placeholders/) or take a look at this [Bootstrap Grid module](http://www.nishtechinc.com/Blog/2018/February/Bootstrap-Grid-System-with-Sitecore-9-Dynamic-Placeholders)

Comment: Thanks Jammykam for your time. I will go through this link and will share my views on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] - To avoid the content author involvement,  I have used a new apporach.
Instead of passing the seed id for each Row & Column from the cms, I have written a method which takes the item id as a parameter and extract the integer part of it and use it as a seed value for dynamic placeholder.